# I get an error undefined reading push in React

Tags: reactjs

This is my code. I'm having an error undefined reading push. I want to pass City to another component.

```
    const onInputCityChangeHandler = (e) => { 
      setCity(e.target.value);
    };
    
    const submitForm = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      props.history.push({pathname: "/",city,});
      console.log(city);
    };
```

Comment: Please provide a better explanation and use **'backticks'** to highlight your code blocks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you using functional based components.
So there is no need to pass history in props.
Instead of this use this hook:

```
const history = useHistory()
```

If you are using react-router-dom v6 then,

```
const history = useNavigate()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, its working, if you could help me with how we can use city in another components pass through event listener?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this way

```
const COMPONENT1 = () => {
    const history = useHistory();
    const [city, setCity] = React.useState(null);

    const onInputCityChangeHandler = (e) => {
        setCity(e.target.value);
    };

    const submitForm  = () => {
        history.push({
            pathname: city,
        });
    };

    return (
        <form>COMPONENT1</form>
    )
};

const COMPONENT2 = () => {
    const history = useHistory();

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(history.pathname)
    })

    return (
        <div>COMPONENT2</div>
    )
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, but this does not work.